# python 3 open and read url without url name

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have gone through the relevant questions, and I did not find answer to this one:

I want to open an url and parse its contents.

When I do that on, say, google.com, no problem.

When I do it on an url that does not have a file name, I often get told that I read an empty string.

See the code below as an example:

```
import urllib.request

#urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.whoscored.com", "http://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores"]
#urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com", "http://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores"]
urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores"]
print("Type of urls: {0}.".format(str(type(urls))))
for url in urls:
    print("\n\n\n\n---------------------------------------------\n\nUrl is: {0}.".format(url))
    sock=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print("I have this sock: {0}.".format(sock))
    htmlSource = sock.read()
    print("I read the source code...")
    htmlSourceLine = sock.readlines()
    sock.close()
    htmlSourceString = str(htmlSource)
    print("\n\nType of htmlSourceString: " + str(type(htmlSourceString)))
    htmlSourceString = htmlSourceString.replace(">", ">\n")
    htmlSourceString = htmlSourceString.replace("\\r\\n", "\n")
    print(htmlSourceString)
    print("\n\nI am done with this url: {0}.".format(url))
```

I do not know what does that I sometimes get that empty string as a return for urls that don't have a file name--such as "www.whoscored.com/LiveScores" in the example--whereas "google.com" or "www.whoscored.com" seem to work all the time.

I hope that my formulation is understandable...

Comment: It exist some libraries in Python, like BeautifulSoup to parse content. I'm not sure what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site is coded to explicitly reject requests from non-browser clients. You'll have to spoof creating sessions and the like, ensuring that Cookies are passed back and forth as required. The third-party [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library can help you with these tasks, but the bottom line is you are going to have to find out more about how that site operates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, which I suppose is the short version of the first answer I got for this post;+>

Are there so many ways for a site to operate?

Would you elaborate on this and/or point to a place that will help me find out about it, thanks!

Comment: Well I guess the `automate` package would be a good place to start. But be careful - there are many other hHTP requirements.

Comment: You can see how much of a newbie I am, what is the automate package, where do I find it, and, what can I do with it!

Comment: Hardly surprising, since I now discover I got the name of the package wrong - I actually meant [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked intermittently for me  but using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and sending  the user-agent worked perfectly:

```
headers = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0,(X11; U; Linux i686; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.1): Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'}
urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/LiveScores"]
import requests

print("Type of urls: {0}.".format(str(type(urls))))
for url in urls:
    print("\n\n\n\n---------------------------------------------\n\nUrl is: {0}.".format(url))
    sock= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("I have this sock: {0}.".format(sock))
    htmlSource = sock.content
    print("I read the source code...")
    htmlSourceString = str(htmlSource)
    print("\n\nType of htmlSourceString: " + str(type(htmlSourceString)))
    htmlSourceString = htmlSourceString.replace(">", ">\n")
    htmlSourceString = htmlSourceString.replace("\\r\\n", "\n")
    print(htmlSourceString)
    print("\n\nI am done with this url: {0}.".format(url))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

And since you mention requests, yes, I had seen something about it in another post here, and that brings me, if you bear with me, to another question:

I have tried to install requests, and apparently it did not work because I still get the "no module named requests" message. What can I do about it?

Would it help to mention that I installed anaconda a while ago, and I could see from the installation process that anaconda took over python34.

I hope you can give me some good ideas so that I can go on.